# Issue with Linking a 32-bit NASM file on a 64-bit machine

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

So I'm learning x86 NASM assembly, and I'm making my first little program.

The NASM code is

```
extern printf

segment .data

prompt1 db  "Hello World!", 0   ; Null-terminated

segment .text

global main

main:
  pushad

  push dword    prompt1
  call          printf
  add           esp, 4
  popad
  ret
```

I then do `nasm -f elf32 HelloWorld.asm`, which creates a HelloWorld.o file.  Then I do `gcc -m32 HelloWorld.o -o HelloWorld`.

This returns an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
```

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The use of `-m32` and `elf32` was on the advice of various other StackOverflow threads.  I've tried installing stuff like the i386 GCC and G++ libraries (which fixed issues where it was saying the architecture was wrong).

As the title says, this is 32-bit assembly but my laptop is 64-bit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably don't have the 32 bit libraries installed. Depending on your distribution, you need some packages such as `gcc-multilib`

Comment: I've installed gcc-multilib and (and g++-multilib to see if that helped; it didn't)  I just fixed it though; turned out I had to install libgcc32-4.8-dev.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by installing libgcc32-4.8-dev.  I had already installed gcc-multilib so perhaps the combination of the two was what I needed.